# Psalms/Tehillim 18:26

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

In [Psalms 18:26](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16239#v26):

> עִם־חָסִ֥יד תִּתְחַסָּ֑ד **עִם־גְּבַ֥ר** תָּ֜מִ֗ים תִּתַּמָּֽם

Why is the word עם־גבר vocalised as עִם־גְּבַ֥ר `ʕim-ggəvár` instead of עִם־גֶּבֶר `ʕim-ggέvɛr`? I am asking this because גֶּבֶר `ggέvɛr` seems to be the usual vocalisation.

Also, curiously, the Secunda renders this word as γαβρ `gabr`, which would correspond to Tiberian Hebrew גֶּבֶר `ggέvɛr` <sup>(a)</sup>.

I have heard various explanations from different people, here listed in order of credibility (according to me):

1. Raba (=Ibn Ezra) says that גְּבַר `ggəvár` is an adjective and is not in construct [with תָּמִ֗ים `tʰɔmíym`] <sup>(b)</sup>, but I'm not sure what he meant by adjective, or what this tells us about the relationship between גְּבַר `ggəvár` and גֶּבֶר `ggέvɛr`.
2. Rashash (=Samuel Strashun) quoted Rambam (=Maimonides) saying that גֶּבֶר `ggέvɛr` is sometimes called גְּבַר `ggəvár`, but I tried to look at Rambam's original statement <sup>(c)</sup>, and I couldn't quite reach the same conclusion.
3. גְּבַר `ggəvár` is the Aramaic version of גֶּבֶר `ggέvɛr`. <sup>(d)</sup> While this is true, it doesn't explain why an Aramaic word ended up in the middle of a psalm.
4. Someone suggested that גְּבַר `ggəvár` is simply the construct of גֶּבֶר `ggέvɛr`, but I could not find evidence of this claim; on the contrary, the construct of גֶּבֶר `ggέvɛr` seems to again be גֶּבֶר `ggέvɛr` <sup>(e)</sup>.
5. Someome suggested that they are the same word, and the stress was simply moved backwards for poetic purposes.

I would appreciate if someone can clarify the whole situation. In my limited knowledge of Hebrew grammar, I don't think a segolate `CέCεC` can have a form that is `CəCáC`, as they belong to different templates.

---

### Footnotes

<sup>(a)</sup> [R. A. Carrera Companioni](https://repository.sbts.edu/handle/10392/6977)'s transcription of a [9th-century manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrosiano_O_39_sup.) of [Origen's Hexapla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexapla) has the second part of Psalms 18:26 as:

> **ουεμ γαβρ** θαμιμ θεμαμ̣μ̣α̣μ̣

This **γαβρ** `gabr` seems to reflect the segolate `ggέvɛr` (before the evolution of segolates CaCC > CɛCɛC).

<sup>(b)</sup> [Ibn Ezra on Psalms 18:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.18.26.1):

> גבר - תואר ואיננו סמוך

My translation: גבר `ggəvár` - adjective and not construct

<sup>(c)</sup> [Rambam on Mishnah Bekhorot 7:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_on_Mishnah_Bekhorot.7.5.1):

> ובעל גבר על משקל ארץ ולפעמים קורא גבר על משקל גובל [גבר על משקל גבל כדכתיב זקני גבל (יחזקאל כז ט)]

My translation: ובעל גבר `uvaʕal ggέvɛr` in the template of ארץ `έrεṣ`, sometimes pronounced גבר `√gbr` in the template of גובל (`govál`??) [גבר `√gbr` in the template of גבל `gəvál` as the scripture says זקני גבל `ziqnéy gəvál` in Ezekiel 27:9]

This is what I don't understand, because according to my understanding, Rambam is saying that `ggέvɛr` is sometimes pronounced `ggovár`, but then in brackets he is saying `ggəvár`? But `ggovár` and `ggəvár` are different pronunciationns, so why would Rambam put the latter in brackets as if the latter was explaining the former?

For context, this is a commentary on Mishnah Bekhorot 7:5 listing conditions which would disqualify one from priesthood, one of which is וּבַעַל גֶּבֶר `uvaʕal ggέvɛr`.

<sup>(d)</sup> [Targum Onkelos Genesis 2:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Onkelos_Genesis.2.24) says:

> :עַל כֵּן יִשְׁבּוֹק **גְּבַר** בֵּית מִשְׁכְּבֵי אַבוּהִי וְאִמֵּהּ וְיִדְבַּק בְּאִתְּתֵהּ וִיהוֹן לְבִסְרָא חָד

<sup>(e)</sup> [Zechariah 13:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16217#v7) says:

> :חֶ֗רֶב עוּרִ֚י עַל־רֹעִי֙ **וְעַל־גֶּ֣בֶר עֲמִיתִ֔י** נְאֻ֖ם יְהֹוָ֣ה צְבָא֑וֹת הַ֚ךְ אֶת־הָֽרֹעֶה֙ וּתְפוּצֶ֣יןָ הַצֹּ֔אן וַֽהֲשִֽׁבֹתִ֥י יָדִ֖י עַל־הַצֹּֽעֲרִֽים

although someone expressed doubt as to whether גֶּ֣בֶר is in construct state here. But another line of evidence is that segolates CeCeC seem to always have construct state the same CeCeC.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147739/discussion-on-question-by-leaky-nun-psalms-tehillim-1826); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.